# Custom View with Bindings in a NSTableCellView

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, cocoa-bindings

i have an XCode 4 project for mac desktop. It has a tableview in it that uses NSTableCellViews. The TableView is connected to an NSArrayController to provide it's content. This is using bindings for custom labels and the like, which has worked out rather well.

I have a custom view that i would like to put in the NSTableCellView, which will use custom drawing based on a NSNumber value from my Table Cell View binding.

Since XCode 4, you can no longer have ibplugins, which means i can no longer create custom bindings for interface builder to work with. How can I still get this value to my custom view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `NSTableCellView` subclass you can bind the custom view's property to a property in the `-objectValue` method of the cell. Like so:

```
[self.customView bind:@"title"
             toObject:self.objectValue
          withKeyPath:@"name"
              options:nil];
```

And pass the binding you want bound to the custom view to objectValue.name in interface builder.

Comment: i didn't do it this way, however this is an elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Where in the NSTableCellView subclass should this go? My table view is bound to an array controller and in this array of objects, one of the object properties is "type" which is an NSString. How do I bind this? I am not sure what @"title" is in the answer above. Is it an IBOutlet to the NSTextField in the cell view?